# TFlite Model that runs on a List of tensor Images

Tags: tensorflow

So I'm stuck trying to feed this model input data, it's supposed to take an array of TensorImages, but I'm stuck doing it, if someone could help me with it I would really appreciate it, I can't figure it out.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
fun getCount(interpreter: Interpreter): Int {
    var images = getImages()
    images = preprocessImages(images as ArrayList<TensorImage>) as ArrayList<TensorImage>
    var listImages = mutableListOf<TensorBuffer>()
    for(i in 0 until images.size){
        listImages.add(i,images[i].tensorBuffer)
    }
    var imgBatches = mutableListOf<List<TensorBuffer>>()
    imgBatches.add(0,listImages as List<TensorBuffer>)

    var inputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape(),interpreter.getInputTensor(0).dataType())
    var outputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createDynamic(interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).dataType())


    inputBuffer.loadArray(imgBatches,interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape())
    interpreter.run(inputBuffer,outputBuffer)
    interpreter.close()
    Log.d("Output", outputBuffer.toString())
    return 0
}
```

The error is

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
```

loadArray(FloatArray!, IntArray!) defined in org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer
loadArray(IntArray!, IntArray!) defined in org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer

when I call inputBuffer.loadArray

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a Kotlin Mutable list to inputBuffer.loadArray()
It needs to be one Array. The quickest fix is to pass the images one by one in a loop. I also suggest you look into [ImageProcessor](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/image/ImageProcessor) to prepare your input, it will help you avoid further bugs. I don't know what the format of the image is and what the output is supposed to be but assuming it's a bitmap:

> @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
> fun getCount(interpreter:Interpreter): Int {
>
> ```
> val imageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
>
>     .add()
> ...
> .add()
>     .build()
>
>
>
> var images = getImages()
>
> for (img in images) {
>
>     val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(img))
>     val inputBuffer = tensorImage.tensorBuffer
>
>     val pred = interpreter.process(buffer)
>     val outputBuffer = pred.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
>     
>     
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: It doesn't work, it requires a batch of 64 images, I don't know how to do that transformation in java or kotlin

Comment: @FirasSOLTANI It would help if you could be more precise. What doesn't work? What requires a batch of images? What transformation don't you know how to do?